# Which ports are required to connect to SQL Server from tiny_tds?

Tags: sql-server, networking, centos, tiny-tds

There is not route between the web server (CentOS, 192.168.10.100) and the SQL Server  (192.168.12.200).

I have installed `tiny_tds` on the web server. Which network ports are required to add to the routes in order for `tiny_tds` to read/write SQL Server data?

Comment: `MSSQL server` uses port 1433 (TCP) by default. sry, don't know anything about `tiny_tds`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The default SQL Server port is 1433, and client ports are assigned a random value between 1024 and 5000.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/287932

`tiny_tds` follows the default ports.

Answer (score 2):

By default SQL Server runs on 1433 port but you can configure that in SQL Server Configuration Manager.

Go to SQL Server Network Configuration -> {PInstance} -> TCP / IP and you’ll see a list of IP addresses and ports SQL Server is configured to use by default. Make sure that IP address you are using to reach SQL Server is enabled in SQL Server Config manager.

If this still doesn’t work you might want to check connection string and/or post some code here.